# How to replace all words not starting with dash in gvim?

Tags: vim

I have a text file which has patterns like:

```
-a a -b b -c c -d d
```

I would like to replace all words not starting with `-` with `z`. So the expected text is

```
-a z -b z -c z -d z
```

I tried `%s/^(-\(.*\))/z/g` but this seems to replace everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is the greediness of `*` (see `:h /star`, which says `Matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as many as possible.`).

The question states that only words need to be replaced, so we use the word atom `\w`. We **cannot** use

```
" don't use
:%substitute/[^-]\w\+/z/g
```

because the `[^-]` matches a character, including spaces, and breaks things.

We think we need a negative look-behind instead:

```
" don't use this either
:%substitute/-\@!\w\+/z/g
```

Now, the problem is that `aaa` in `-aaa` matches: the first `a` is not a `-`, so vim happily says *that's a match*.

So we're going to do non-regex.

The idea is to search for `-\w\+`, then skip to the next word and do the change (this is heavily based on the input pattern):

```
" these should be typed in normal mode
/-\w\+<ENTER>
W
ciwz<ESC>
```

Having typed these, you could finish the whole file with `nW.`, but that's at least one more character than I want to type, and I hate the shift key sometimes. So we turn it into a macro:

```
qqnW.q
```

And replay as many times as you like with one of

- `@q`
- `@@` (after having run `@q` at least once)
- `100@q` (we want to pick a large number to cover the whole file)

---

I've omitted the unnecessary parentheses from the original regex. I also omitted the `^` because, from the samples given, not all text to replace is at the beginning of the line. See `:h /^`. Finally, I changed `*` to `\+` so that we only match if, in fact, there are word characters to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That is the closest I got to it. However, this seems to replace the words that begin with -. So the results here is z a z b z c z d. I would like to replace the words that do not begin with - to get -a z -b z -c z -d d.

Comment: Hi, Why would this not work if there are multiple characters after -? For example:     -abcd abcd -bcd bcd -cd cd -d d. I thought the w+ would take care of this. Sorry about the follow up questions, I have been trying to figure this out for sometime now.

Comment: @GargiSharma it really should work that is strange... i can test later this evening and see

Comment: @GargiSharma more updates: the issues of regex are unfortunately intuition-defying in some cases. The `[^-]` was matching incorrect places, and trying to fix it with a negative look-behind only made it more wrong. So this was the closest I could get. If the input is dramatically different from `-word word`, then this may not work

Comment: Thanks for helping @D. Ben Knoble!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution using `:s` would be:

```
:s/\(^\|\s\)\zs[^- \t]\S*/z/g
```

This starts by matching either the start of the line with [`^`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5E), or a whitespace character with [`\s`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cs), using a [`\|`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fbar) to match one or the other and using [`\(` and `\)`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28) to match that as a group (to prevent `^` from matching on its own.)

Then we use [`\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) to mark the start of the match we'll capture. So we found a whitespace, but we're not really replacing it, only what follows.

Then we use [`[^- \t]`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fcollection), which is a collection uses `^` to match any character other than `-`, a space or a tab character `\t` (end of line will not match either.) (An alternative here is to use `[^-[:space:]]`, which uses the [`[:space:]`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D) character class.)

Then we match zero or more non-space characters with [`\S*`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CS). The repetition with [`*`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fstar) is greedy, so it will match the longest sequence of non-blanks.

The end result is that you match full sequences of non-whitespace characters (words) and only the ones that do not start with `-`. Matching whitespace or beginning of line explicitly helps ensure the start of words is properly anchored.

Comment: Yeah, we needed WORD boundaries actually!  The [`\<`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3C) match comes close, but unfortunately it matches the boundary based on [`'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27), which IMO is not exactly what we need here... Tweaking `'iskeyword'` might make this work, but I think that's a bit fragile, even if it can be made to work... `\zs` to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this approach: Substitute space plus letter by space z

```
:%s, [a-z], z,g
```